# I'm using Xcode 14 and have this error "Custom build rule which produces it?"

Tags: swift, swiftui, configuration, frameworks

I'm trying to create an IOS app using ML Kit from google. After running "pod install" command and execute my "VisionWithRoomExample.xcworkspace" I tried to build my application and I have this issue:

"error build: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Guilherme/Documents/VisionWithRoom/DerivedData/VisionWithRoomExample/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/VisionWithRoomExampleObjC.app/VisionWithRoomExampleObjC'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?"

I change my workspace settings to "Custom & relative to workspace" following instructions from Apple Developer Forum to tried to resolve my issue, but didn't work.

Link to Apple Community Issue: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716483?login=true&page=1#736417022

Please, someone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: This is likely because your `info.plist` file cannot be found. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116142)

Comment: have a look at this link you will find the solution here.
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-build-rules-for-custom-file-types